# Did the Kohen Gadol wear Tzitzit?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzitzis, tetzaveh, kohen-gadol

When reading about the Kohen Gadol's 8 garments you don't see any mention of Tzitzit!

Is it mentioned anywhere if the Kohen Gadol wore Tzitzit?

I know that a man is only obligated to wear Tzitzit on a garment with 4 corners. However, we specifically wear a 4 cornered garment, in order to obligate us to wear Tzitzit, to show our love for the Mitzvah.

Shouldn't the Kohen Gadol, the representative of all Jewry be a leading example for all the Mitzvot?!